# Initializing a costmap_2d with a static_map

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to initialize a costmap_2d with a static map which is being published by map_server. Could someone point me to how this would be done?

I understand that I need to run a map_server node which publishes /map and /map_metadata topics. Also I realise that I need to use a tf::TranformListener to get the map data to the costmap. Is that correct ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sagnik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12194/initializing-a-costmap_2d-with-a-static_map/) by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2011-12-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on 2011-12-02**:
Also, to put it out there, I would be using this costmap_2D for doing global planning using nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner (sbpl_lattice_planner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your launch file, include the following:

```
<node name="map_node" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" 
      args="$(find your_package)/config/map.yaml" 
      respawn="false" output="screen" />
```

The file "map.yaml" could look like this:

```
image: empty_map.png
resolution: 0.0500000000
origin: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
```

In a file called global_costmap_params.yaml, you could include:

```
global_costmap:
    publish_voxel_map: true
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    update_frequency: 3.0
    publish_frequency: 0.0
    static_map: true
    rolling_window: false
```

And finally, in your launch file, you should put the following under move_base:

```
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base_node" output="screen">
    ...
    <rosparam file="$(find navigation_config)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-12-05**:
All global planners adhere to this interface: http://ros.org/wiki/nav_core#BaseGlobalPlanner. So, the simplest thing to do is probably to write some code that uses that interface, loads a planner plugin, and hooks it up to the map server. There's nothing I know of that does this out-of-the-box.

**Comment by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on 2011-12-02**:
Is there a cleaner way to use a global planner to generate a plan given a map in ROS, without any Control at all ? Thanks.

**Comment by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on 2011-12-02**:
Thank you for your answer. Actually I am trying to use sbpl_lattice_planner to generate a global plan. I have a non-ROS based Controller, and hence do not want a local Controller that move_base provides. It does not seem trivial to me to pluck out just a global plan if using move_base.